# String to byte Python

Tags: python, string, hex, byte

I'm trying to convert a string into a byte. The string contains an integer that I have to convert in hex.
For example: example :
stringAddress = '32000'
I want that to become byte = b'\x7D\x00\x00

My code gives me back byte =b'`\\`x7d`\\`x00`\\`x00

when I try to "replace" the `'\\'` the byte changes... in b'}\x14\x00'

This is my code

```
from codecs import encode


numero = '32020'
numerohex = hex(int(numero))[2:]
print(numerohex)

 

if len(numerohex) == 4:
    newnumero = r'\x{}\x{}\x00'.format(numerohex[:2], numerohex[2:4])
elif len(numerohex) == 3:
    newnumero = r'\x0{}\x{}\x00'.format(numerohex[:1], numerohex[1:3])
elif len(numerohex) == 2:
    newnumero = r'\x00\x{}\x00'.format(numerohex)
elif len(numerohex) == 1:
    newnumero = r'\x00\x0{}\x00'.format(numerohex)

 

tmp = bytes(newnumero, encoding='raw_unicode_escape')

 

print(bytes(newnumero, encoding='raw_unicode_escape'))
print(encode(newnumero.encode().decode('unicode_escape'), "raw_unicode_escape"))
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `hex(int(stringaddress))`?

Comment: if I do that I have this result '0x7d14' that isn't want I need

Comment: `bytes.fromhex(hex(int(stringAddress))[2:])` gives `b'}\x00'` - is that what you want?  Note that Python bytes representation will show an ASCII character if a byte corresponds to a printable ASCII character, so you always get `b'}'` rather than `b'\x7d'`.

Comment: sorry @snakecharmerb i need exactly b'\x7d' there isn't something that don't convert it in b'}'

Comment: @MatteoCarlino No, not unless you hack the CPython runtime to change the built-in `__repr__` of `bytes` objects. But almost certainly, you dont' need that. Those are the bytes you want, why do you care how it is represented when printed to a terminal? You can always format the string however you want

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry but is the first time that i use byte and i thought that what python print is what i had in the variable

Comment: @MatteoCarlino it is? I think what you actually may want is `int(string_address).to_bytes(2, 'big')`

Comment: There's no point in your code that the result `b''\\x7d\\x00\\x00'` is obtained. Only `b'\\x7d\\x14\\x00'` and `b'\x7d\x14\x00'`, and that's because you typed `32020` instead of `32000` as you described in the question..